# antisymmetric matrix show that orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve Hughston Tod's Problem 2.10)

> The Transpose of a matrix $A_{ij}$ is the matrix $\tilde{A}_{ij}=A_{ji}$. A matrix is called symmetric if $A_{ij}=\tilde{A}_{ij}$, and antisymmetric if $A_{ij}=-\tilde{A}_{ij}$. A matrix is called orthogonal if $A_{ij}\tilde{A}_{jk}=\delta_{ik}$. Suppose $P_{ij}$ is antisymmetric, and that $\delta_{ij}+P_{ij}$ has an inverse $Q_{ij}$ Show that $A_{ik}=(\delta_{ij}-P_{ij})Q_{jk}$ is orthogonal.

I went about this problem in the following way:

If $$A_{ik}=(\delta_{ij}-P_{ij})Q_{jk}$$ then $$\tilde{A}_{ij}=(\delta_{ik}+P_{ik})\tilde{Q}_{kj}$$
Then multiplying $$A_{ik}\tilde{A}_{ij}=(\delta_{in}-P_{in})\underbrace{Q_{nk}(\delta_{km}+P_{km})}_{=\delta_{nm}}\tilde{Q}_{mj}=\delta_{ij}$$
The last equality can be verified by taking the Transpose of the term in the braces.

Did I do everything correct?

Comment: In more traditional notation, you're being asked to show that the [Cayley transform](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform#Matrix_map) of a skew symmetric matrix, $(I-P)(I+P)^{-1}$, is orthogonal.

Comment: Proofs in the usual (non Einstein-summation) notation are given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325784/a-is-skew-hermitian-prove-i-a-1-ia-is-unitary).  Whichever notation you use, it's important to keep matrices in the correct order and justify any "switching around".

Comment: I don't quite see how the problem I defined is related to the Cayley Transform of a skew symmetric matrix.

Comment: do you not see that $Q=(I+P)^{-1}$?

Comment: No I don't quite see that.

Comment: Alright.  First, note that the matrix whose entries are $\delta_{ij}$ is the identity matrix, commonly denoted by $I$. So, $\delta_{ij} + P_{ij}$ is the same as $I + P$.  So, the inverse of that matrix (which is our $Q$) is $(I+P)^{-1}$.  Does that make sense now?

Comment: yes that makes sense. Thx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You took the transpose incorrectly.  You should find
$$
\tilde A_{ij} = (\delta_{jk} - P_{jk})Q_{ki} 
= Q_{ki}(\delta_{jk} - P_{jk}) = 
\tilde Q_{ik} (\delta_{kj} + P_{kj})
$$

Comment: how does the rest then work out? cause then you have the Q's multiplied and they don't yield the identity?